# Solve the equation $x^{x^5} = 5$ over $\Bbb R.$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, exponential-function, contest-math

Find real numbers $x$ (if any) such that $x^{x^5} = 5.$

I have shown that $x \notin \Bbb Z.$ Does there exist any $x \in \Bbb R \setminus \Bbb Z$ which satisfies the above equation? Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: A similar question was in the first round of Israel $2011$.

Comment: Do you mean Israel Mathematics Olympiad 2011 @Michael Rozenberg?

Comment: Yes. There was $x^{x^{2011}}=2011.$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As $x^{x^5} = 5$, we can always substitute the $5$ on the index with $x^{x^5}$
$$\begin{array}{rcll}
x^{x^5} &=& 5\\
x^{x^{x^{x^5}}} &=& 5\\
\end{array}$$

Repeat infinitely many times and you will get:

$$x^{x^{x^{x^{\cdots}}}} = 5$$

The index that $x$ is raised to, is same as the entire "power tower", which is 5:

$$x^{\boxed{x^{x^{x^{\cdots}}}}} = 5$$
$$x^5 = 5$$

We get $x = \sqrt[5]{5}$.

Answer (score 5):

\begin{align} 
x^{x^5}&=5
\tag{1}\label{1}
\end{align}

Equation \eqref{1} can be solved formally
with the help of the Lambert W function:

\begin{align} 
x^5\ln x&=\ln 5
,\\
5x^5\ln x&=5\ln 5
,\\
x^5\ln (x^5)&=5\ln 5
,\\
\ln (x^5)\,\exp(\ln (x^5))&=\ln 5\exp(\ln5)
.
\end{align}

At this point we can apply the Lambert W function:
\begin{align} 
\operatorname{W}(\ln (x^5)\,\exp(\ln (x^5)))
&=
\operatorname{W}(\ln 5\exp(\ln5))
,
\end{align}
and since the argument 
$\ln 5\exp(\ln5)>0$,
there is just one solution

\begin{align} 
\ln (x^5)&=\ln5
,\\
x^5&=5
,\\
x&=5^{\tfrac15}\approx 1.379729661
.
\end{align}

---

**Edit**

Or, less formally, without Lambert W function:

\begin{align} 
(x^{x^5})^5&=5^5
,\\
x^{5x^5}&=5^5
,\\
(x^5)^{(x^5)}&=(5)^{(5)}
,\\
x^5&=5
.
\end{align}

Comment: How do you ascertain that $y^y = 5^5 \implies y=5$?

Comment: @math maniac: By direct substitution of 
$y=5$ into $y^y = 5^5$.

Comment: It may so happen that there are more solutions? How do you guarantee @g.kov that the solution is unique.

Comment: @math maniac: You are absolutely right,
in general there could be more solutions,
that's why using Lambert W is preferable in this case.

Comment: The last solution is clear and all steps fully justified. I wonder why you belittle it.

Comment: @Allawonder: Yes, in this case. 
But consider slightly modified $x^{x^a}=a$.
Following the same steps we always get one root $a^{\tfrac1a}$,
but for $0<a<1$, we will always miss the other root, 
e.g. for $a=\tfrac12$ the missed root is $\tfrac1{16}$. 

Lambert W approach gives $\exp(\tfrac1a\operatorname{W}(a\ln(a)))$
and automatically covers all that cases,
for $a<1$ the second root would be $\exp(\tfrac1a\operatorname{W_{-1}}(a\ln(a)))$,
we don't need to worry about missing solutions.

Answer (score 3):

The hint.

$\sqrt[5]5$ is the root.

Now, prove that it's an unique root for which consider two cases:

1. $0<x\leq1$;
2. $x>1$.

Comment: The function $f(x) = x^{x^5} - 5$ is strictly increasing in $\Bbb R_{> 0}.$

Comment: @math maniac. No! On $(0,1)$ it's not so.

Comment: What will happen if $x < 0$?

Comment: @math maniac. Nothing. The domain of $x^{x^5}$ is $(0,+\infty).$

Comment: Why is the domain of $x^{x^5}$ considered as $(0, + \infty)$? The function is defined at the negative integers too.

Comment: @mathmaniac. But then $x^5$ is a negative integer too, so $x^{x^5}$ is in $[-1,1]$.

Comment: @math maniac.Take $x=-\frac{1}{2}.$ If we want to work with the function $f(x)=x^{x^5}$ we need a domain $(0,+\infty).$ By the way, you showed that $x\not\in\mathbb Z$.

Comment: @Michael Rozenberg my point was that how do I make sure that there exists no $x \in (- \infty, 0)$ where $x^{x^5} -  5$ is defined such that $x^{x^5} - 5 = 0$?

Comment: @math maniac We said about this already. No? By definition if we work with real numbers, so the domain of $f(x)=x^{x^5}$ it's $(0,+\infty).$ If you say before (which not so in our case) that we work in $\mathbb Z$ then $x\neq0$ and consider two cases: $x$ is odd; $x$ is even.

Comment: I said before that I have shown there exists no $x \in \Bbb Z$ so that $x^{x^5} = 5.$ That doesn't mean that I have worked for all negative reals. It may so happen that there is a negative real $x$ such that $x^{x^5}$ is defined and is equal to $5.$ But how do I show that can't be possible or in other words there exists no negative real number $x$ where $x^{x^5} = 5.$ Does it make sense? Please let me inform if I am wrong in any of my above arguments.

Comment: Why do we unnecessarily restrict the domain to the set of positive reals? There are infinitely many negative reals too where the given function is well defined.

Comment: @math maniac. Because we want to work with this function. We can calculate a value of the expression $x^y$ for all $x>0$, which says that we can work with this expression on $(0,+\infty).$ For example, we can wright $x^y=e^{y\ln{x}}$, which helps to get a new results. If we think about $x^y$ for $x\leq0,$ so for $x=0$ we obtain the first trouble: What happens if $y=-1$? For $x<0$ we have the following trouble: $x=y=-\frac{1}{2}.$ By the way, if we work in $\mathbb Z^2$ we can wright $(-1)^{-2}=1,$ but you want a real solutions of the equation. If so, we must  work in $(0,+\infty).$

Comment: @math maniac. The first thing, what you need to understand, it's the following. By definition if we work in $\mathbb R$,  the domain of the function $f(x)=x^{x^5}$ is $(0,+\infty).$ I tried to explain why we take this definition, but you did not read it maybe. In any case, if we work in $\mathbb R^2$ the expression $x^y$ has the following domain:$\{(x,y)|x>0,y\in\mathbb R\}$. Id est, for $x=-1$ the expression $x^y$ is not defined.

Comment: By domain do you mean open and connected set?

Comment: @mathmaniac.: Only moderators can remove comments of other users. However if comments contain various keywords, flagging them may cause them to be removed instantly (or at least lower the standard flagging threshold for a comment to be removed automatically).  And in either case, users are always free to flag comments to request that the moderators delete them for various reasons. This has nothing to do with reputation and moderation advantages (which do exist regarding actual posts on the site).

Answer (score -2):

Here are graphs that show the solution, $x = \sqrt[5]{5}$:

[image]

Comment: @mathmania:  No no no.  The *abscissa* value is $\sqrt[5]{5}$... a wonder to behold.