# Solve $x^{x^5} = 5$ for $x$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

A friend who tutors high school math showed me this equation. I could not solve it. But by trial & error in Python I discovered $\sqrt[5]{5}$ is the answer. Further realized that for any integer $n$, $x^{x^n} = n$ is solved by $\sqrt[n]{n}$. How does one handle such equations by ordinary algebraic methods?

Comment: Please use MathJax for typesetting mathematics in this site, instead of Python notation. If you are not familiar, [here's a tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Solve the equation $x^{x^5} = 5$ over $\Bbb R.$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3335552/solve-the-equation-xx5-5-over-bbb-r)

Comment: $\bigg(x^\overbrace{x\bigg)^x\bigg )^\cdots \bigg )^x}{\mathrm{n\;times}}$

Answer (score 2):

Suppose $x^{x^n}=n$.

$$\log\left(x^{x^n}\right)=x^n\log x=\log n$$

Take the substitution $\log x=y$ (or $x=e^y$).

$$\left(e^{y}\right)^ny=ye^{yn}=\log n$$

$$\left(e^{y}\right)^ny=yne^{yn}=n\log n$$

Let $m=e^n$, then $\log n=m$

$$yne^{yn}=me^m$$

As the function $y=xe^x$ is injective in the interval $[-1,\infty)$ (which can be seen easily on a graph), if we make the assumption $m\ge-1$ (i.e. $n\ge e^{-1}$), then we have

$$yn=m=\log n$$

$$y=\frac{\log n}{n}$$

$$\log x=\frac{\log n}{n}$$

$$x=e^{\frac{\log n}{n}}=\left(e^{\log n}\right)^{\frac1n}=n^{\frac1n}=\sqrt[n]{n}$$

For example, if $n=5$ then we have $x=\sqrt[5]{5}$, like you found.

---

If $x$ or $n$ is a complex number, or if $n<e^{-1}$, then the argument

$$yne^{yn}=me^m\iff yn=m$$

fails, because $y=xe^x$ ceases to be injective. In that case, you may need to use the [Lambert W function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function). $x=\sqrt[n]{n}$ will remain a solution, but it will not be the *only* solution.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** Let $y=x^5$, then you have $(y^{1/5})^y=5\iff y^{y/5}=5\iff y^y=5^5$

Comment: It seems to me that you have been absent for a while. If this is the case, *Welcome back !*

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Thanks - frequency dropped a lot due to other things.  Hopefully will be able to visit more going fwd.